# SWT - Closing a dialog window from a different class

Tags: java, dialog, swt

Let me try and explain what I am talking about better.

Main GUI has a button that when clicked opens Dialog A
Dialog A's OK button runs a method in the main GUI

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
       baseDialog.startPrintOperation();
}
```

When the `baseDialog.startPrintOperation()` method finishes, I want dialog A to close.

How can I close Dialog A from a method in a different class?

**EDIT**

Here is the okButton in Dialog A

```
okButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        getPlotterSelection();
        getSpinnerValue();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              baseDialog.startPrintOperation();
           }
          };

          if(Display.getCurrent() != null) {
             r.run();
          }
          else {
             Display.getDefault().asyncExec(r);
          }
      }
  });
```

Here is the section of the printOperation method that needs to close Dialog A.  This method is in the MAIN GUI class

```
finally {
           plotOp.removeOperationListener(this);
           plotOp = null;
           Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                 removeAllTableRows();
                 plotRequestCompleted = true;
                 THIS is where I want to close Dialog A;
              }
           });
        }
     }
  });
  session.queueOperation(plotOp);
```

} // end startPrintOperation()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke   `Dialog.public boolean close()` once you finish the print call.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not following the suggestion.

Comment: Pls use Dialog.close() method to close the dialog. Override okPressed() method in your dialog and invoke print operation in okPressed() method.

Comment: "Dialog A's OK button runs a method in the main GUI"---This is wrong way of doing things. Please do all the stuff that your dialog is supposed to do and close the dialog. Do not delegate dialog's task to main GUI class.

Comment: I will try to move the Method from the main GUI to Dialog A